# Interface will not rename under systemd

Tags: networking, systemd, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to rename a network interface on an Ubuntu 16.04 VPS, but am unable to do so. Systemd names my primary network interface enp0s3. I want to rename this interface to eth0.

According to the [systemd.link documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html) I created a file called `/etc/systemd/network/10-eth0.link` with the following content:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=08:00:27:f7:57:e5

[Link]
Name=eth0
```

The MAC address matches the one given in the `ip a` output for the interface. I also renamed the enp0s3 entries to eth0 in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Although, when I reboot the machine, the interface is still named enp0s3.

The following entries in the `dmesg` output are interesting to me:

> e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) 08:00:27:f7:57:e5
>   e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
>   e1000 0000:00:03.0 enp0s3: renamed from eth0

So apparently, it starts out as eth0, but is then renamed back to enp0s3 again. I am not sure why?

When I try to debug the link file, I get the following output:

```
$ sudo udevadm test-builtin net_setup_link /etc/systemd/network/10-eth0.link
calling: test-builtin
=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          229
file size:         6841778 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1755242 bytes
nodes              5086456 bytes
Load module index
timestamp of 'etc/systemd/network' changed
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Parsed configuration file /etc/systemd/network/10-eth0.link
Created link configuration context.
unable to open device '/sys/etc/systemd/network/10-eth0.link'

Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

The line about it being unable to open the device seems odd. I'm not sure why it's trying that, there is no etc directory under /sys at all, should I create it?

Any insights into why my interface name doesn't stick is very welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html, the default naming policy is:

```
#  /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
[Link]
NamePolicy=kernel database onboard slot path
MACAddressPolicy=persistent
```

So I suspect you might want to add the following line to your eth0.link:

```
NamePolicy=mac
```

I haven't tested this, so I am not certain, but I suspect the issue is that you Match on MAC, but there is no naming policy to make that stick.

> Each of the policies may fail, and the first successful one is used. The name is not set directly, but is exported to udev as the property "ID_NET_NAME", which is, by default, used by a udev rule to set "NAME". If the name has already been set by userspace, no renaming is performed

It is just a guess though.

You should also be able to just disable the default.link, at least per https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

On some openSUSE systems I run, I had a similar issue, which (in addition to having had to use the 99-default.link 'trick') was resolved by creating two files under /etc/udev/rules.d (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118272/80-net-setup-link-no-longer-functions-when-i-downgraded-systemd, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Device_names and https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Udev/Upgrade_Guide):

`sudo touch /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` (or just make sure an empty file of that name is in that location)

AND

I created /etc/udev/rules.d/10-persistent-network.rules:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="eth*", ATTR{tx_queue_len}="1000"
```

In your case, you could actually use that file to set the name you want:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net",ATTR{address}=="08:00:27:f7:57:e5",NAME="eth0"
```

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion. Although setting the NamePolicy and disabling the default link both did not change anything. The interface is still renamed to enp0s3 after a reboot.

Comment: Thank you for adding additional details to your answer. Adding the udev rules files did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

I've tried all of the above. Nothing works. I have been researching constantly for 2 weeks.

I did find an answer AND IT WORKS.
Here:

https://superuser.com/questions/914646/renaming-network-interface-with-systemd

The post contains a link to Lennart's notes, which help not at all. read the post and you should win.

Here is how I got it to work:

Step 1: 
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-local-net-names.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="74:da:38:68:55:c1", NAME="wlan1"

This file needs to be ordered before /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules

This works on Debian Stretch. It should work on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: In my Debian Stretch, the file is /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules, not at /usr/lib/...

Answer (score 2):

Acording to systemd docs, this is due to the new [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)

Docs say you have three options to disable that behaviuor, and probably the third one is the easiest one:

1. You disable the assignment of fixed names, so that the unpredictable kernel names are used again. For this, simply mask udev's .link file for the default policy: ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link
2. You create your own manual naming scheme, for example by naming your interfaces "internet0", "dmz0" or "lan0". For that create your own .link files in /etc/systemd/network/, that choose an explicit name or a better naming scheme for one, some, or all of your interfaces. See systemd.link(5) for more information.
3. You pass the net.ifnames=0 on the kernel command line

Comment: I tried all three of these solutions, unfortunately the name still did not change. Something is still overruling it.

Answer (score 0):

The [examples](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html#Examples) now explicitly state that you need to set `NamePolicy=`:

```
[Link]
NamePolicy=
Name=eth0
```

so that `Name=eth0` takes preference. Otherwise the default `NamePolicy` takes precedence.

I tested this and can confirm that it fixes the issue.

Comment: The example you linked to no longer says `NamePolicy=` must be set, but it does say the `.link` filename must start with a number.